# Solving $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac1{x^2}\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac1{4x^2}(x \: + \: \sqrt{x} -8)y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \dfrac{1}{x^2}\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{1}{4x^2}(x \: + \: \sqrt{x} -8)y = 0$$

Comment: Ok, but how far have you tried until getting stuck?

Comment: No hope for analitic answer. Maple or Mathematica can't solve.

Comment: Is the square in the second coefficient in error? Then the leading terms give an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic roots $1\pm\sqrt3$. The perturbation series giving a solution expansion could then be in the powers of $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What method are you using? Tried the Frobenius method?
Since this cannot be solved by algebraic methods..see if coupled with Leibniz-Maclaurin method ...

1. Assume  a trial solution of the form
   $x^c( {a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...+a_rx^r+...})$
2. Differentiate the trial series ( for y" and y')
3. substitute the results in the equation l
4. equate coefficients of corresponding powers of the variable on each side of the equation.